# Symfony2 i18n routing - defining an array of requirements

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to define an array of locales used in Symfony2 routing rules, so that I won't have to repeat it over and over in every route and alter it for each route separately in case I change the supported languages list?

I know it's very easy to do a quick *search & replace* in `routing.yml`, *but* the issue's scope could be easily expanded so that it provokes a question like this: is it possible to provide this locale array externally (i.e. to have it read from a database)?

For clarification - here is an example of what I have now:

```
page_show:
    pattern: /{_locale}/page/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: myCompanymyBundle:Cms:pageShow }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|pl
        slug: "[^,]+"

news_archive:
    pattern: /{_locale}/news/archive
    defaults: { _controller: myCompanymyBundle:Cms:newsArchive }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|pl
```

And here is an example of what I'd like to have:

```
page_show:
    pattern: /{_locale}/page/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: myCompanymyBundle:Cms:pageShow }
    requirements:
        _locale: languages
        slug: "[^,]+"

news_archive:
    pattern: /{_locale}/news/archive
    defaults: { _controller: myCompanymyBundle:Cms:newsArchive }
    requirements:
        _locale: languages
```

Where `languages` is an array, be it a YAML array or a PHP array provided externally; it's not really substantial.

This could be very helpful to further ease the configuration of the application I'm writing. I'd like to extract as much configuration as possible into the config.yml file. So that if I decide that, for instance, I want to add a new language quickly and I already support it in the business logic and templating layers, I just have to modify the languages array in `config.yml` and voila, it's done.

Comment: @vibaiher Nope. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thats something that bugs me every time. The only thing I could offer is to put your requirement params into app/config/parameters.yml

```
# src/App/Resources/config/routing.yml
sport:
    pattern: /{_locale}/{sport}
    defaults: { _controller: App:Vote:vote }
    requirements: { _locale: %routing_locales%, sport: %routing_sports% }

# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    # routing requirement regex
    routing_sports:    'hockey|football' # available sports so far
    routing_locales:   'de|fr' # available locales so far
```